# Integração boleto Itau ShopLine em PHP

Tags: php, integração, boleto, pagamento-online

Estou tentando desenvolver uma integração com o sistema de boletos online do itau o Itau Shopline em PHP, porém toda vez que eu envio os dados pra URL de comunicação eu recebo uma pagina com essa mensagem:

> Problemas na criptografia ou o campo valor está incorreto. Entre em
>   contato com o SOS Itaú Bankline.

Originalmente o script para autenticação está em Java,  porém eu encontrei [esta classe em PHP](https://github.com/gabrielrcouto/php-itaucripto) que foi recriada com base na classe original em Java.

Oque poderia ser a razão desse erro?

Comment: Chegou a entrar em contato com SOS? a mensagem é bem generica, acredito que eles podem dar mais informações.

Comment: Ja tentei todos os numeros, mas o suporte do Itau é horrivel quase nulo, impossível falar com os numeros de telefone que eles dão, sempre ocupado, ou quando atende te transferem pra tanto atendente que a ligação cai

Comment: A chave de criptografia tem um tempo pra propagar, faz quanto tempo que você gerou ela ?

Comment: Como eu nao tenho acesso a conta do cliente, ele quem gerou e me enviou por e-mail, o mesmo me foi enviado as 16h de ontem. Qual o tempo pra propagação?

Comment: O tempo é até 24 horas se não me engano, aguarde mais um pouco, pode ser também que o seu cliente tenha gerado com letra minusculas, aguarde dar 24 horas ou um pouco mais, tente de novo, se não der só entrando em contato mesmo, mas provavelmente é uma dessas duas opções.

Comment: Eu vi que no painel de configuração do Itau você informa o dominio do site que vai utilizar o sistema, como estou realizando os testes locais, isso pode ser um problema, ou não interfere em nada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse [link](http://lojadoc.insv2.com/?page_id=716) diz assim:

> Este erro está relacionado a Chave, e pode ter como causa o cadastro errado da chave nas configurações do módulo, ou pelo fato de após a geração da Chave a mesma demora até 24hrs para liberação, neste último caso, aguarde a liberação e tente novamente, em caso do erro persistir entre em contato com o Itaú informando a ocorrência.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,

Apenas para contribuir com outras pessoas que venham a passar pela mesma situação que passei, o problema na verdade é que a porcaria da documentação fala para o cliente que ele deve gerar a chave de criptografia em minúscula no bankline mas você no código deve necessáriamente usar ela em maíusculo.

```
$encrytionKey          = strtoupper('1g2a3u4h88s10201');
```

Foi só fazer isso e aquele popup horroroso (coisa do passado isso) abriu.
Cá para nós está na hora do itau se atualizar sobre esses métodos, eles não conhecem REST não ?